# How do I get my Firefox passwords if I can't log into Windows but can see the Windows filesystem from Linux?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, ubuntu-9.10

My dual-boot computer is fubar but I can log into Linux and see the Windows filesystem.

One of the biggest losses is all of the passwords I had stored for sites in Firefox.

Is there any way to retrieve these by digging around in the Windows filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passwords are in a sqlite file inside your [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder), so you can not see them by just browsing your Windows' filesystem

The easiest is to copy the profile from `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile folder>`
 into your Linux's Firefox by using [this procedure in mozillazine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder), and then see the passwords when you launch Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to copy your old (Windows) Firefox profile to your current one (Linux).
C:\Documents and Settings\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\

to

~/.mozilla/firefox/

Or you can only copy key3.txt file, and the signons3.db from your Windows profile to your Linux profile.

Those file name could be a different one depending on the version of firefox you are using.